# Can I specify a group_by field dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Take a group by command like this

> persons.group_by(&:age)

Instead of group by the same field each time, I would like to pass a variable for the field name.

In Ruby, is it possible to dynamically specify which field to group?

So something like this?

> persons.group_by(@field)

Comment: `persons.group_by {|p| p.send(@field) }`?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
group_name = :age

persons.group_by(&group_name)
```